# JUNIT Parameters error: Wrong number of arguments

Tags: java, junit, parameterized

I'm using JUnit parameterized test and appears this error:

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of arguments

This is the code:

Test:

```
@Parameters
public static Collection<Object[]> spreadsheetData() throws IOException {
    InputStream file = new FileInputStream("c:\\Path\\to\\file\\jeje.xls"); 
    return Utils.loadFromExcel(file);
}
```

Method:

```
public static Collection<Object[]> loadFromExcel(final InputStream excelFile)
throws IOException {
    HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(excelFile);

    Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

    // Number of columns
    int numberOfColumns = countNonEmptyColumns(sheet);
    int rows=0;

    // Number of rows
    for (Row row : sheet) {
        rows++;
    }

    Object[][] datos = new Object[numberOfColumns][rows];

    for (int row = 0; row<rows; row++) {
            for (int column = 0; column < numberOfColumns; column++) {
                Cell cell = sheet.getRow(row).getCell(column);
                datos[column][row] = cell.getRichStringCellValue();
            }   
    }

    return Arrays.asList(datos);
}
```

I don't know what's wrong.

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 1):

I assume that each row in the spreadsheet is a test data set and that each column is a parameter to your test.
If this is the case, you need to change your array declaration to `Object[][] datos = new Object[rows][numberOfColumns];` and to populate the array accordingly.

**Example**

Given this spreadsheet...

```
a    b
c    d
e    f
g    h
```

... your current implementation of `loadFromExcel()` will return the collection below. A new row in the spreadsheed will add a new element to each of the arrays in the result list but the  size of the result list will stay the same.

```
[a, c, e, g]
[b, d, f, h]
```

I assume, the method should return something like this:

```
[a, b]
[c, d]
[e, f]
[g, h]
```

Each new row in the spreadsheet will add a new array with two elements to the result list.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I change that error, but the problem still the same, appears the Wrong number of arguments error

Comment: Your unit test class must have a public constructor with the same number of arguments as columns in your excel sheet (i.e. the array size of entries returned by the `spreadsheetData()` method)

Comment: Thanks. Finally I pass the data like this format:

    return Arrays.asList(new Object[][] {{new Object[]{data1, data2}}, {new Object[]{data1, data2}}});